# Nginx Redirect based on what is contained in the url

Tags: regex, nginx

I am a noob when it comes to redirect and rewrites and such...  My goal is to do a redirect based on what is sent to the server.
Example of the urls that will be sent:

https://example.org/git/#123

https://example.org/git/!123

and redirect to url based if ! or # is part of it
if ! then it would go to
https://git.example2.com/userhere/repohere/merge_requests/123
if # then it would go to
https://git.example2.com/userhere/repohere/issues/123

Some help with a nginx location block would be nice.

Comment: You can’t match #123 because server never sees it.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t match #123. So you need to use different character i.e &

Use below sample rule.

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)/!123)"{
return 301 https://git.example2.com/userhere/repohere/merge_requests/123;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)/!456)"{
return 301 https://git.example2.com/userhere/repohere/merge_requests/456;
}
```

Comment: Ok i had to make an edit to my post.  The thing is the numbers 123 will be ticket number or merge request numbers.  !456 would reference merge request url https://example.org/git/!456 which redirect to https://git.example2.com/userhere/repohere/merge_requests/456

#456 would reference merge request url https://example.org/git/#456 which redirect to https://git.example2.com/userhere/repohere/issues/456
So the # or ! has to be regex off and compared to see what it is and if !SOMENUM go to the merge_request url and pass the number to the end if not go to issues url and pass num to the end

Comment: Maybe if statement checking if ! at the front redirect to the merge_request url else issue url   assuming I can still send a link with the #123 since I can't match it.  I know regex u can do something like (!|#) and it will match either one so not sure how to do it in this